# Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup code review

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

records=[]
keep_looking = True
url = 'https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter'
while keep_looking:
    re = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text,'html.parser')
    data = soup.find_all('section',attrs={'class':'fcListing'})
    for d in data:
        event = d.find('a').text
        date = d.find('span',attrs={'class':'datetime'}).text[1:-4]
        location = d.find('span',attrs={'class':'venue-location'}).text
        mainEvent = first.find('span',attrs={'class':'bout'}).text

    url_tag = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'fightcenterEvents'})

    if not url_tag:
        keep_looking = False
    else:
        url = "https://www.tapology.com" + url_tag.find('a')['href']
```

I am wondering if there are any errors in my code? It is running, but it is taking a very long time to finish and I am afraid it might be stuck in an infinity loop. Please any feedback would be helpful. Please do not rewrite all of this and post, as I would like to keep this format, as I am learning and want to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is not the right site to seek help for review related task, I considered giving a solution as it sounds that you may fall in an infinite loop according to your statement above.

Try this to get information from that site. It will run until there is a next page link to traverse. When there is no more new page link to follow, the script will automatically stop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests

url = 'https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter'

while True:
    re = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text,'html.parser')
    for data in soup.find_all('section',attrs={'class':'fcListing'}):
        event = data.select_one('.name a').get_text(strip=True)
        date = data.find('span',attrs={'class':'datetime'}).get_text(strip=True)[:-1]
        location = data.find('span',attrs={'class':'venue-location'}).get_text(strip=True)
        try:
            mainEvent = data.find('span',attrs={'class':'bout'}).get_text(strip=True)
        except AttributeError: mainEvent = ""

        print(f'{event} {date} {location} {mainEvent}')

    urltag = soup.select_one('.pagination a[rel="next"]')
    if not urltag: break  #as soon as it finds that there is no next page link, it will break out of the loop
    url = urljoin(url,urltag.get("href")) #applied urljoin to save you from using hardcoded prefix
```

For future reference: feel free to post any question in [this site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get your code reviewed.

Comment: i will reference the below site from now on. This has given me some new things to learn and this was very helpful.

Comment: one question: how do you store it into a list, so i can then put all the data in a DataFrame and then export to a csv? @SIM

Comment: Before print statement create a line like `items = [event,date,location,mainEvent]`, then `print(items)`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: kind of. so after i run the script above i want to do the below: import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['event','date','location','mainEvent']), but i am getting the error message --> 'Shape of passed values is (1, 4), indices imply (4, 4)'.

Comment: If you have further questions on this topic, you should create a new post describing your current requirement. Thanks.